# Let $A$ and $B$ be well-ordered sets, and suppose $f:A\to B$ is an order-reversing function. Prove that the image of $f$ is finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be well-ordered sets, and suppose $f:A\to B$ is an
order-reversing function.  Prove that the image of $f$ is finite.

I started by supposing not. Then we must have that the image of $f$, or the set $\{f(x)\in B:x\in A\}$, has infinite cardinality. If this is the case the we must have that $\vert{\{f(x)\in B:x\in A\}}\vert\geq \aleph_0$ which also means there exists a strictly order-preserving function $g:\mathbb{N}\to \{f(x)\in B:x\in A\}$.

The contradiction I am trying to reach is that this would imply that there exists an order-reversing function from $\mathbb{N}$ to an infinite image which is a subset of a well-ordered set which can't happen but I don't know how to close the gap in the argument.

Comment: Do you mean that $g$ is (strictly) order-**reversing**?

Comment: Incidentally, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set#Necessary_and_sufficient_conditions_for_finiteness: "In Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory without the axiom of choice (ZF), the following conditions are all equivalent: $1.$ $S$ is a finite set. That is, $S$ can be placed into a one-to-one correspondence with the set of those natural numbers less than some specific natural number. [$\ldots$] $3.$ (Paul Stäckel) $S$ can be given a total ordering which is well-ordered both forwards and backwards. That is, every non-empty subset of $S$ has both a least and a greatest element in the subset."

Answer (score 1):

Let $C=f(A)$ the image of $f$ with the order induced by $B$. Every non-empty subset of $C$ has minimum and maximum. This implies that every element in $C$ distinct from the minimum has immediate predecessor and every element distinct from the maximum has immediate successor. Let $c_1$ the minimum of $C$. For every natural number $n$, we choose $c_{n+1}$ in $C$ as the immediate succesor of $c_n$ if $c_n$ is distinct from the maximum of $C$. If this process stop we are done. Otherwise we have a a strictly order preserving function $g:\mathbb{N}\to C$ wich is not suryective. Let $c$ be the minimum of $C\setminus g(\mathbb{N})$. And let $d$ the immediate predecessor of $c$ in $C$. By election of $c$, there exists a natural number $k$ such that $d=c_k$. Then $c=c_{k+1}$ is in $g(\mathbb{N})$. A contradiction.

EDIT:
We can also follow your approach in this way: For every natural number $n$, let $a_n$ in $A$ such that $f(a_n)=c_n=g(n)$. Let $D=(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and consider the restriction $f:D\to f(D)$. Then the bijection $f^{-1}\circ g:\mathbb{N}\to D$ is a strictly order reversing function and $D$ is a well-ordered set. This is imposible by the argument above.

Comment: How does this do what I want to do? I am searching to contradict that there exists no order-reversing function $f:\mathbb{N}\to A$ with infinite image when $A$ is well-ordered. Now  I see why the argument that I was looking for works now. I am actually just looking for clean wording in a proof. The comment below is also very helpful but it is not the route I want to take for my proof.

Comment: I prefer write it in detail. The important point is that every non-empty subset of $f(A)$ has maximum. So for example, in the notation of your approach, $g(\mathbb{N})$ has a maximum and that is a contradiction.

Comment: I edit my answer. Maybe that's what you want.

Comment: Your restricted function $f$ in your edited comment is not nessecarily injective by the way you described it. The reason being is that there may be multiple values in $A$ that satisfies "$f(a_n)=g(n)$" meaning that your defined $a_n$ is not unique. I believe it would be better to state something like "For every natural number $n$, let $a_n$ be the smallest value in $A$ such that $f(a_n)=g(n)$" so that you can be sure that the restriction is indeed injective.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well but I think I'm taking one $a_n$ for each natural number $n$. Note that $c_n=c_k$ if and only if $n=k$ so I think the restriction is injective. By abuse of notation, I write $f=f|_D^{f(D)}$ and $D=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: That is true and is very deceptive. Since $f$ is only order-reversing we can have say $2$ and $3$ be in $A$ and say they map to $5$ in the image of $f$. Also we can say $g$ maps $m\in\mathbb{N}$ to $5$ or in other words we would have  $g(m)=5=f(2)=f(3)$ and therefore $a_m=2$ or $a_m=3$.

Comment: Yes, you can choose $a_m=2$ or $a_m=3$ in that case, but only one. For example, if we say 'let $x$ be a real number greater than $3$' there are many possibilities for $x$ but it is understood that $x$ is only one of those possibilities and and it remains the same through the proof.

Comment: You are right but it is better to be more explicit  about which value you will be choosing.

Comment: We don't want to be more explicit because we want that the proof to be valid for every possible choice.

Answer (score 0):

By the givens, each non-empty subset of $f(A)$ has both a minimal and a maximal element. Conclude that $f(A)$ cannot contain a subset isomorphic to $\omega$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The image of $g$ is a non-empty subset of a well-ordered set. Therefore it has a minimal element.